# cron - bash-script with if statements on exit code and grep

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm relatively 'beginner' in the world of Linux and bash and I cannot figure this out.

Among other things I want to modify iptables if 'string' doesn't exist in there, but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure if this is because of the if statements, exit code, syntax or sudo permissions or other.

When the script is being run automatically via cron, it performs the `if` clause even if `iptables` does contain the string I'm looking for. This is verified by

1. printing iptables in terminal both seconds before and after a scheduled run
2. by adding an `echo "this" >>/log/file.log` to the if clause.

Take 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -L -n -v | grep 8.8.8.8
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    command-to-perform
fi
```

Take 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptablesvar=$(iptables -L -v -n)
if [[ $iptablesvar != *"8.8.8.8"* ]]; then
    command-to-perform
fi
```

I've tried both, triggered by (sudo) crontab with the following line:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/username/path/to/script-file.sh
```

What baffles me, is that both the options above seems to work when entered directly into the terminal like so:

```
sudo iptables -L -n -v | grep 8.8.8.8
if [ $? != 0 ]; then echo "not found" ;fi
if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo "found" ;fi

var=$(sudo iptables -L -n -v)
if [[ $var != *"8.8.8.8"* ]]; then echo "n" ;fi
if [[ $var == *"8.8.8.8"* ]]; then echo "y" ;fi
```

What gives?

If relevant, my system is a fresh Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia

Comment: A lot useful links, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612444/bash-script-runs-manually-but-fails-on-crontab

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error (what error?) or do you get some incorrect result (what result?). Also not that you can't test `$?` twice. The first test would change `$?`.

Comment: Sorry, edited original post explaining "does not work". And yes, I know the exit code changes after the first if, I was trying to communicate that both those if's work in terminal.

Comment: Who's crontab is running the script?

Comment: root? "sudo crontab -e".

Comment: Are you sure it's not simply that `iptables` is not in cron's `PATH` (so that you're testing the exit status of a failed `iptables` command, rather than the exit status of `grep`)? Try adding the full path ex. `/sbin/iptables`

Comment: @steeldriver solid tip, thanks. Added full path to all commands - looks like maybe that did the trick! Another thing I noticed (not sure if relevant) was that the content in my variable was 'broken' when i echo'ed without quotes - `echo $var` instead of `echo "$var"` resulted in a mucked up mixture of the actual iptable and folder names/paths from ~ ...

Comment: For an explanation of the second issue, see [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: @steeldriver feel free to submit an answer on cron PATH/full path to command, and I'll gladly accept it as an answer.

Comment: Since you're running this from root's crontab you don't want (and shouldn't include) `sudo` in the script itself.

Comment: I know, and I haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this myself then - all credits to [@steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver)'s [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580159/cron-bash-script-with-if-statements-on-exit-code-and-grep#comment1080152_580159):
`iptables` is not in cron's `PATH`. Changed command to include full path `/sbin/iptables`.