# starting GUI application on other users display via roots cron

Tags: bash, sudo, cron, display

I'm trying to automate the connection of a VPN tunnel via cron upon system boot.
I have a bash-script triggered by roots cron `sudo crontab -e` (because some other commands needs elevation).

I'd be fine using piactl (cli), but when trying to connect I get a message saying the client needs to be started, so...
One of the steps I'd like to perform is to start an GUI application (pia-client) on my non-root users display.

The following command works directly from terminal:

```
sudo su
runuser -l $username -c 'DISPLAY=:0 /opt/piavpn/bin/pia-client &> /dev/null &'
```

However, when I put that into my script is doesn't work.
The script is executable `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh` and other commands in the same script is working.

Anyone have a solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing as I've already asked this exact question only days ago. Didn't even realize...

The solution is to add full path-to-command as the command is not in cron's `PATH`.
Changed the code to:

```
sudo su
/sbin/runuser -l $username -c 'DISPLAY=:0 /opt/piavpn/bin/pia-client &> /dev/null &'
```

Source/credit: [@steeldriver's comment on this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580159/cron-bash-script-with-if-statements-on-exit-code-and-grep#comment1080152_580159)